# Removing first two digits in an octal value in C

Tags: c

I want to print file permission in octal format.

I've used the stat system call and a stat structure to retrieve the permission field.

All I want to do is print it with the last 4 digits but the field has 6 digits.

That is,

```
struct stat s1;
stat(somefile, &s1);
printf("%o", s1->st_mode);
```

will print out six digits, the first two I want to discard. Is there some kind of trim function that I can use to do this?

I'm not looking for a long way, just a simple quick way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood the question:

you need to get only the last 4 digits getting rid of all the rest, then

```
int a = 234348;
int b = a & 07777;  
printf("a = %o\nb = %04o\n", a, b);
```

will output :

```
a = 711554
b = 1554
```

**In your case :**

```
printf("%04o", (s1->st_mode & 07777));
```

Comment: Edit was being done while you were commenting :D , I wish SO adds a function that tells the others `User is editing his answer` lol @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `07777` would be slightly more readable than `0xfff` here, since it shows the intent to mask the last four octal digits

Comment: Also, adding the `0`-flag to the format, and a field-length of 4 might be appropriate.

Comment: absolutely agree with u @MattMcNabb ;)

Comment: How can I go from 5 digits to 4?

Comment: @Zaphod whatever the number of digits you have if you `&` it with the mask `07777` you will go to 4 digits, try the code with `a = 6346`

Comment: I am using this and my output is going from 100664 to 664. Maybe it is ignoring the leading 0?

Comment: yes because it is a zero! you can `printf("%04o", b);` for example or do whatever to adapt to your needs @Zaphod

Comment: Add my previous comment, and the output will be 0-padded to 4 digits.

Comment: @Deduplicator. Where does this flag go?

Comment: @Deduplicator : thank you dude, and sorry didn't see your previous comment till now

Comment: As an aside, in this particular case: `#ifndef ALLPERMS`  `# define ALLPERMS (S_ISUID|S_ISGID|S_ISVTX|S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)`  `#endif`  `int b = a & ALLPERMS;`